# Bison: Conflicts: 1 shift/reduce error

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm trying to build a parser with bison and have narrowed all my errors down to one difficult one.

Here's the debug output of bison with the state where the error lies:

```
state 120

   12 statement_list: statement_list . SEMICOLON statement
   24 if_statement: IF conditional THEN statement_lists ELSE statement_list .

    SEMICOLON  shift, and go to state 50

    SEMICOLON  [reduce using rule 24 (if_statement)]
    $default   reduce using rule 24 (if_statement)
```

Here are the translation rules in the parser.y source

```
%%

program              : ID COLON block ENDP ID POINT
                     ;
block                : CODE statement_list
                     | DECLARATIONS declaration_block CODE statement_list
                     ;
declaration_block    : id_list OF TYPE type SEMICOLON
                     | declaration_block id_list OF TYPE type SEMICOLON
                     ;
id_list              : ID
                     | ID COMMA id_list
                     ;
type                 : CHARACTER
                     | INTEGER
                     | REAL
                     ;
statement_list       : statement
                     | statement_list SEMICOLON statement
                     ;
statement_lists      : statement
                     | statement_list SEMICOLON statement
                     ;
statement            : assignment_statement
                     | if_statement
                     | do_statement
                     | while_statement
                     | for_statement
                     | write_statement
                     | read_statement
                     ;
assignment_statement : expression OUTPUTTO ID
                     ;
if_statement         : IF conditional THEN statement_lists ENDIF
                     | IF conditional THEN statement_lists ELSE statement_list
                     ;
do_statement         : DO statement_list WHILE conditional ENDDO
                     ;
while_statement      : WHILE conditional DO statement_list ENDWHILE
                     ;
for_statement        : FOR ID IS expression BY expressions TO expression DO statement_list ENDFOR
                     ;
write_statement      : WRITE BRA output_list KET
                     | NEWLINE
                     ;
read_statement       : READ BRA ID KET
                     ;
output_list          : value
                     | value COMMA output_list
                     ;
condition            : expression comparator expression
                     ;
conditional          : condition
                     | NOT conditional
                     | condition AND conditional
                     | condition OR conditional
                     ;
comparator           : ASSIGNMENT
                     | BETWEEN
                     | LT
                     | GT
                     | LESSEQUAL
                     | GREATEREQUAL
                     ;
expression           : term
                     | term PLUS expression
                     | term MINUS expression
                     ;
expressions          : term
                     | term PLUS expressions
                     | term MINUS expressions
                     ;
term                 : value
                     | value MULTIPLY term
                     | value DIVIDE term
                     ;
value                : ID
                     | constant
                     | BRA expression KET
                     ;
constant             : number_constant
                     | CHARCONST
                     ;
number_constant      : NUMBER
                     | MINUS NUMBER
                     | NUMBER POINT NUMBER
                     | MINUS NUMBER POINT NUMBER
                     ;              
%%
```

When I remove the if_statement rule there are no errors, so I've narrowed it down considerably, but still can't solve the error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How come your syntax doesn't end and if-else with endif as it does with all other such constructs?

Comment: also, i'm not entierly sure but i think I've solved similar problems with specifying a special "else_statement" that can be either ``else statement`` or empty and specifying if as ``if statment else_statement``

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't believe I missed that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this statement: if condition then s2 else s3; s4

There are two interpretations:

```
if condition then
   s1;
else 
   s2;
s3;
```

The other one is:

```
if condition then
   s1;
else
   s2;
   s3;
```

In the first one, the statment list is composed of an `if` statement and `s3`. While the other statement is composed of only one `if` statement. That's where the ambiguity comes from. Bison will prefer shift to reduce when a shift-reduce conflict exist, so in the above case, the parser will choose to shift `s3`.

Since you have an `ENDIF` in your `if-then` statement, consider to introduce an `ENDIF` in your `if-then-else` statement, then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing `ENDIF` in the `IF-THEN-ELSE-ENDIF` rule.